Swagger endpoint returning 404
I am using springdoc (springdoc-openapi v2.6.0) with my spring boot project. This is my security config
   new AntPathRequestMatcher("/xyz/**"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs/**"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs/**"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v3/api-docs"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-resources"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-resources/**"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**"),
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/webjars/**"));

over local it works fine. But over the server, I am getting 404 over swagger-ui/index.html as well as /v3/api-docs
